# Does ECMAScript 6 have a native way to call REST Web Services

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading a tutorial on the web on ES6 and I am pretty sure that I read that there is a native way to call REST Web services by using ES6.

Now I am googling on that topic and I just cannot find it.

so in ES6 do I still need libraries like jquery/lodash etc to make web service calls? or can I make such calls using just the new language constructs?

Sorry if this is FAQ. I will delete the question if its very commonly asked... but I have really tried searching and found nothing. But I am very sure that I read somewhere that now we can call the REST endpoint directly without any external library.

Comment: "[The XMLHttpRequest object is the ECMAScript HTTP API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20121206/)."

Comment: There is no EC6. Did you mean ES6? Where does this come from, I've heard it from so many people now?

Comment: _The XMLHttpRequest object is the ECMAScript HTTP API_. - Yeah, so I thought too.
But [the very link you supply](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) says otherwise.
Both the [Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) and the
[XMLHttpRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) were created by
[the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG)](https://whatwg.org/news/start)
which was formed in June 2004.
Hence, neither _Fetch_ nor _XMLHttpRequest_ are _ECMAScript_ constructs.
However, plain JavaScript can access the corresponding objects in modern web browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ES6 (aka ES 2015) does not have a new API that makes consuming REST services any easier than it had been previously.

I suspect you might be looking for the new DOM API that aims to replace XMLHttpRequest called **fetch**. Only Chrome and Firefox implement this API at the time of this writing: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

The `fetch` API can be polyfilled, here's a good one: https://github.com/github/fetch

More info on the fetch API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
http://github.github.io/fetch/

Basic usage:

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => console.log(users));
```

Comment: You should add that this API has nothing to do with ES6, but is a DOM API.

Comment: to extend on @Bergi 's comment, https://github.com/request/request this can be used when not in a browser.

Answer (score 4):

> Does ecmascript 6 have a native way to call REST Web Services

To answer your question directly: no.

ECMAScript itself has a very limited standard library. It doesn't provide any I/O APIs. Any I/O APIs are provided by the host environment, such as Node or the browser. Those pretty much evolve independently of ECMAScript.

You can find the spec here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ .

> But I am very sure that I read somewhere that now we can call the REST endpoint directly without any external library.

Depends on the environment. Browsers have supported [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for ages. jQuery is merely a wrapper around that API, so there was never a *requirement* to use jQuery. jQuery cannot do anything that the browser environment cannot.

Node provides [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).